# How to use flyway with gradle? First migration depends on gradle build

Tags: gradle, flyway, build.gradle

I'm using gradle and now adding flyway to my project. I have problem with first migration - V1__xxx.sql. Sometimes it is executing, sometimes it's not.

### Given

I have 3 migration files:

- V1__create.sql -- creates person1 table
- V2__create_db.sql -- creates person2 table
- V3__Create_person_table.sql -- creates person3 table

I've done 4 test cases trying to get what's going on.

### When

Before each one I did: 
    `gradle clean flywayclean`

Test Case 1. creates tables: person2, person3

```
gradle flywayinit flywaymigrate
```

Test Case 2. creates tables: person1, person2, person3

```
gradle flywaymigrate
```

Test Case 3. creates tables: person1, person2, person3

```
gradle build flywaymigrate
```

Test Case 4. creates tables: person2, person3

```
gradle build flywayinit flywaymigrate
```

### Then

I was expecting that all three tables: person1, person2 and person3 will be created every time. But they don't

### Questions

I don't have any failure logs nor warnings. But sometimes first table is not created. And I want to ask you:

1. Why does it work that way? Why sometimes the first sql is executed and sometimes it's not? What am I missing?
2. How should I properly use gradle clean/build and gradle flywayclean/init/migrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flywayinit` is for adding flyway to an existing production database that already has tables with data in it.

In that scenario you create a V1 migration that would set up all the existing production tables. This allows you to set up a new DB from scratch using flyway.

However you obviously don't want to run the V1 migration against production, because those tables already exist and have production data in them. So you run `flywayinit` against your production db and it creates a metadata table as if V1 has already been run, *but doesn't actually run it*. Now you can use flyway to upgrade your production db in the future.

So, in the cases where your first table was not created what you actually did was

- empty your DB (flywayclean)
- tell flyway to pretend V1 was already run in this DB (flywayinit)
- migrate your DB to V3 (flywaymigrate)

TL;DR: don't use flywayinit on an empty database